# Java stream - How to go over a list, show elments and collect them in the same line

Tags: java, java-8, collect

I have the following:

```
Map<String, String> carMap;
List<Car> cars = ......

carMap = cars.stream
.collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.getValue(), key -> key.getColor()));
```

I'm iterating over cars and I'd like to show on screen what is included into the map. I could do something like this after collecting the map but I don't want to go over the list again:

```
cars.stream()
      .forEach(System.out::println)
```

Is there a way to do a sysout in this line?

```
carMap = cars.stream
.collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.getValue(), key -> key.getColor()));
```

I tried with a forEach after stream but obviously didn't work

Comment: you want to store as well as print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just for debugging purposes and you want to collect as well as print, you can simply use `peek` here -

```
Map<String, String> carMap = cars.stream()
    .peek(c -> System.out.println("Value: " + c.getValue() + " and Color: " + c.getColor()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(key -> key.getValue(), key -> key.getColor()));
```

Comment: thanks so much I also tried with map and it worked but peek is much more convenient since we don't want to replace the element